# Is there anyway to get reports and charts using .NET Core Windows Application?

Tags: c#, mysql, charts, report, nuget-package

Can someone please let me know that how I can get reports using MySql database and .NET Core 3.1 C# Windows Application. Is there any NuGet Packages to get Chart and report viewer controls which can support to .Net Core?
I could not see the chart control in toolbox.

[Chart Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL2Kf.png)[.NET Component Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WdoN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Reset toolbox
2. To add chart controls Right-click in the Toolbox and select Choose Items. Then selects the .Net Framework Components Tab. Scroll through the list and find with Name Chart and check the Item having Namespace **System.Windows.Forms.Datavisuvalization.Charting** and **System.Web.UI.Datavisuvalization.Charting** and click OK.
3. Close and Reopen the Visual studio.

Comment: But I couldn't see the chart control in visual studio tool box. I think it is not available in .Net core

Comment: I did this sir. When I choose items in toolbox System.Windows.Forms.Datavisuvalization.Charting and System.Web.UI.Datavisuvalization.Charting checkboxs were already checked. But still I couldn't find chart control.